# vertical tab bar in android

Tags: android, sdk, tabs, tabbar

Does anyone know if it is possible to create vertical tab bar in android or if there is a library out there that provides the capability to do vertical tab bar?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve this by using the following code:

```
getTabWidget().setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
```

[source](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=3862)