# android sidebar navigation without using fragments

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to create an activity that has sidebar on the left that is not changing between activity transitions (like split view in ios). It seems that I can do this with fragments but I need to add support for devices that is prior to HoneyComb.

I tried using a layout something like below.

```
   <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="320dip"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:id="@+id/navLay"
    >
 <ListView
         android:id="@+id/navList"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
     </ListView>

 </LinearLayout>
  <LinearLayout 
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:id="@+id/contentLay"
     ><ListView
      android:id="@+id/contentList"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
  </ListView>
 </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

But the first list is also updated on activity transition. I want to note that the activity is the same activity except the right list's data source is different. So it would be pretty good if I could save state and content of  the left navigation bar while navigating. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [Support Package](http://developer.android.com/sdk/compatibility-library.html) which provides classes for backward compatibility, and includes `Fragment` class also.

Comment: Do I have any other options without using support package?

Comment: `Fragment` would be the easiest way to do it. If you really want to avoid it (I would be interested to know why), then you can use a [Tab Layout](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-tabwidget.html) and check how to [create vertical tab bar](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5875644/1321873)

Answer (score 1):

> It seems that I can do this with fragments but I need to add support for devices that is prior to HoneyComb.

You can use fragments and some new APIs on those devices. Just use [support package](http://developer.android.com/sdk/compatibility-library.html).